# how ll i read the followong json response of a web service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

how will i read the following json response in java script ?

it's a web service response to be handled by javascript, but i can't make it how shall i read the each submission title and start date. 
any help appreciate able.

```
 ([
{
    "submission": {
        "title": "Attended band concert",
        "full": "met with homeroom teacher after concert, very nice, Joker Jr. is         doing well",
        "start_date": "2013-06-18",
        "end_date": null
    }
},
{
    "submission": {
        "title": "she's complaining about",
        "full": "something",
        "start_date": "2013-06-20",
        "end_date": null
    }
}
```

]);

Comment: That isn't JSON. It has `(` and `)` around it.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on this example,

JSON

```
{
"news1": "This is a first sample news feed",
"news2": "This is a second sample news feed",
"news3": "This is a third sample news feed"
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><div id="news1" style="height:100px;width:auto"></div> </li>
  <li><div id="news2" style="height:100px;width:auto"></div></li>
  <li><div id="news3" style="height:100px;width:auto"></div> </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(
  function() {
      $.getJSON('script/news1.js', function(jd) {
   $('#news1').append('<p>' + jd.news1 + '</p>');
   $('#news2').append('<p>' + jd.news2 + '</p>');
   $('#news3').append('<p>' + jd.news3 + '</p>');  
   });  
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Ya but here OP seems to use an array of json objects. A for loop seems to be needed

Answer (score 0):

If you get this answer as a string you have to remove `(` and `)` at the start and at the end. Then you could parse the string to a javascript-object using the jQuery-function `$.parseJSON(string)` and assign the resulting object to a variable, so you can access the attributes as usual.

```
var object = $.parseJSON(response.substring(1, response.length-2));
```

To access the title of the first submission use `object[0].submission.title` and to access the title of the i-th submission use `object[i].submission.title`.

Answer (score 0):

first remove the `()` with `substring()`;

use the native `JSON.parse()` function to get the json object

then loop through the array.

```
var x=xhr.response,
y=x.substring(1,x.length-2),//or -3
o=JSON.parse(y);
for(var a=0;a<o.length;a++){
 var s=o[a].submission;
 console.log(s.title,s.full,s.start_date,s.end_date);
}
```

shorter way

```
var x=xhr.response;
for(var a=0,b;b=JSON.parse(x.substring(1,x.length-2))[a];++a){
 console.log(b.title,b.full,b.start_date,b.end_date);
}
```

fastest way (reversed)

```
var x=JSON.parse(xhr.response.substring(1,xhr.response.length-2)),l=x.length;
while(l--){
 var a=x[l].submission;
 // even if it's reversed l can be used as index for your elements
 console.log(a.title,a.full,a.start_date,a.end_date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data=[
{
    "submission": {
        "title": "Attended band concert",
        "full": "met with homeroom teacher after concert, very nice, Joker Jr. is         doing well",
        "start_date": "2013-06-18",
        "end_date": null
    }
},
{
    "submission": {
        "title": "she's complaining about",
        "full": "something",
        "start_date": "2013-06-20",
        "end_date": null
    }
}]

   `alert(data[0].submission.title)`//it gives the title  
        alert(data[0].submission.start_date)//gives date
```

> you can also place the for loop to read all the attributes.

```
   for(var i=0;i<=data.length;i++){
      alert(data[i].submission.title)//gives title
      alert(data[i].submission.start_date)//gives date
}
```